# Azure Automation to run Sharepoint Online PowerShell Set-Commands

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, sharepoint-online, azure-automation

I have set up Azure Automation Runbook to run PowerShell which interacts with Sharepoint Online. I'm using 2 modules; Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell and AzureAD. I have same versions in my local machine. Also I have specified credentials for Azure Automation, and those are the same credentials I run on my local machine. For some reason Azure Automation Runbook doesn't execute Set- Commands. If I run the script on my local machine Set-Commands are executed just fine.

```
$myCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'test'

$adminSiteUrl = "https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com"

# Connect to SPOService
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminSiteUrl -Credential $myCred
Get-SPOSite -Identity https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com | select sharingcapability
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com -SharingCapability ExternalUserSharingOnly
```

`Get-SPOSite` is executed and written in output, but`Set-SPOSite` doesn't do anything. I've set Sharepoint External sharing settings from Sharepoint Admin Center UI to Allow SharePoint shares to ExternalUserSharing only and OneDrive shares to disabled. `Set-SPOSite` should change OneDrive sharingcapability to ExternalUserSharing only but it doesn't.

[image: SharePoint Admin Center external sharing settings]

Azure Automation doesn't throw any errors and completes the script successfully. I also tried `Set-SPOUser` cmdlet to modify Site's `IsSiteCollectionAdmin` -property from test user just to test whether it works or not. Once again it worked fine from my local machine but not on Azure Automation Runbook.

**UPDATE**: I tried to implement same script in Azure Function and it behaves exactly same as Azure Automation Runbook. I installed same modules as I'm using in Azure Automation, nothing more. And still no errors in output.

Comment: Looks like authentication issue !? Is your Azure Automation account set to "Run As" ? If yes, double check whether the Azure Automation Run As account's service principal have required permissions to basically set the things related to SharePoint ? If you want to add permissions to read or manage, you will need to grant permissions on the service principal under API permissions tile. For more information, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-web-apis) document. Hope this helps!

Comment: Well it does seem like authentication issue but then it should not get any response from `Get-` cmdlets either. Automation account is set to "Run As", but basically the credentials I pass in to `Connect-SpoService` should be used here, even though it is executed in context of service principal. I did try to add all permissions for that SPN anyway, but it didn't work either.